# Is there a quick way to get the control that's under the mouse?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to find the control under the mouse, within an event of another control.  I could start with `GetTopLevel` and iterate down using `GetChildAtPoint`, but is there a quicker way?

Comment: Why do you need to start at GetTopLevel, couldn't you simply go to GetChildAtPoint directly?

Comment: (a) The control under the mouse isn't necessarily a child of the control whose event is firing, and (b) I would still have to iterate down to find the innermost control.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This code doesn't make a lot of sense, but it does avoid traversing the Controls collections:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point pnt);

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  IntPtr hWnd = WindowFromPoint(Control.MousePosition);
  if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) {
    Control ctl = Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
    if (ctl != null) label1.Text = ctl.Name;
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Need to capture to see mouse move messages...
  this.Capture = true;
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. :-) WindowFromPoint grabs the window handle directly under the mouses position on the screen, regardless of containment. Control.FromHandle translates it into a .Net control (if possible). Boom, done. Very slick.

Comment: Would it not be easier to simulate the mouse click? You can find a link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c)

Comment: What if I want to get the control of another application&

Comment: POINT pt;
HWND hwnd;
GetCursorPos (&pt);
  //find the control or window that lies underneath the mouse cursor.
  hwnd= WindowFromPoint (pt);

Answer (score 2):

Untested and off the top of my head (and maybe slow...):

```
Control GetControlUnderMouse() {
    foreach ( Control c in this.Controls ) {
        if ( c.Bounds.Contains(this.PointToClient(MousePosition)) ) {
             return c;
         }
    }
}
```

Or to be fancy with LINQ:

```
return Controls.Where(c => c.Bounds.Contains(PointToClient(MousePosition))).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm not sure how reliable this would be, though.

Comment: I just used this, it's great to get *every* control under a mouse position. However, it should be c.Bounds.Contains(Point p) not c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Rectangle r).

Comment: `MousePosition` will return a new `point` at each call which is not good for performance, it is better to cache that or better `PointToClient(MousePosition)` into a variable in your loop