# generate a mouse click inside my form application

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, click, visual-c#-express-2010

I am making a program that is designed to send mouse clicks to locations (like an auto clicker but more advanced). I need this to be triggered by a click event. Is it possible to make the click only apply inside a the form along the same principle of a runescape bot? I wish to use the same principle but for a different program. Here is the form I wish for it to apply to the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace web_clicker
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: My english is not good. Could you put dots and commas to make it easier for everyone?

Comment: I won't go after the (obvious) low-hanging fruit this time, and will instead opt to be nice:  [I like mouse clicks too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542.aspx)!

Comment: @Pete i have not asked a question like this one before

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736965/how-to-programatically-trigger-a-mouse-left-click-in-c

Comment: @Brian sorry pages like that confuse me i am dyslexic

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem. But as I understand you try to get the number of clicks in something on form ? 
If yes so that's what I should do :

```
// Definition counter click
private int counter;

// In the C'tor 
counter =0;

// In event click on button or picture or everything else
counter++;
```

And now you have the number of clicking. 
If you don't mean to this answer me I'll try to help you.