# how to move and click a mouse programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, click, controls, mouse

I'm trying to make a simple application involving a moving a mouse and using left and right click. I'm new on this kind of programming where mouse control is involved? can you guys tell me where should I start or give me some basic codes to work with?

What I want to do are:
1. Right click where the current cursor is (this is point A)
2. move on the lower right a bit (this is point B) and left click.
3. repeat.

This is the only code I tried and I found it on other threads.

```
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
        Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
```

Comment: add the code that you tried.

Comment: added i dont really know where should i start.

Comment: [You might have to go low level on this one: here is a link from another stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736965/how-to-programatically-trigger-a-mouse-left-click-in-c)

Comment: You might have to go low level on this one: [here is a link from another post link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736965/how-to-programatically-trigger-a-mouse-left-click-in-c)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx check this out