# Automating MouseClick in C#

Tags: c#, automation, click, mouse, mouseevent

I am very new to winforms and automation in general, and was wondering if there is a simple way to force the cursor to click in C#. I am already moving the cursor to the right spot, and I want to make it perform a click. Is there code that will do this, without getting super complicated. (for clarity, I am automating a mouseclick on a button in another application, which has been opened at this point)

Here is how I set the cursor position:

`Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);`

Comment: Looks like a duplicate question.  See this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to pass `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` to the [`mouse_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try [AutoIt v3](http://autoitscript.com) instead unless you specifically are bound to C#. It's designed for this kind of automation.

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys). AutoIt is also very small, self-contained and will run on all versions of Windows out-of-the-box with no annoying “runtimes” required!

For example:

```
; Double click at the current mouse pos MouseClick("left") 
MouseClick("left")

; Double click at 0,500 
MouseClick("left", 0, 500, 2)   

; SAFER VERSION of Double click at 0,500 - takes into account user's control panel settings 
MouseClick("primary", 0, 500, 2)
```