# .net simulate Mouse Click with application coordinates not screen coordinates

Tags: .net, mouseclick-event

I read this post: [How to simulate Mouse Click in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c).

It was helpful but I could not click the point I want. I think the x and y variables are corresponding to screen coordinates. I wanted to set the values according to my program(form).

Answer (score 1):

to transform your coordinates check following function available in your Form

```
public class Control
{
    public Point PointToScreen(Point p);
}
```

to read/write screen coordinates you may use

```
public sealed class Cursor
{
    public static Point Position { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just needing to click a button?  You can call buttonName.Click

Also, you could add in a label and have onMouseMove update the X,Y.  This may help you get better coordinates

Comment: Hmm. What about this: tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage3; - this was taken from http://www.yevol.com/en/vcsharp2005/controls/tabcontrol.htm

Comment: Better yet, call `Button.PerformClick()`.