# Emulate double click event in Datagrid with touchDown

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, mouse, emulation

i am new using WPF. I have a WPF Window with a datagrid wich launch a process when double click occurs. This work great, but when i do this in a tablet(with windows 7), using the touch screen, the process never happen. So i need to emulate the double click event with touch events. Any one can help me to do this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How to simulate Mouse Click in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c) for how to emulate a mouse click (in windows-forms), but it works in WPF by doing:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

    public void DoMouseClick()
    {
         //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
        int X = //however you get the touch coordinates;
        int Y = //however you get the touch coordinates;
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add a Mouse event click function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns mouse click.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>mouseeEvent</returns>
public static MouseButtonEventArgs MouseClickEvent()
{
    MouseDevice md = InputManager.Current.PrimaryMouseDevice;
    MouseButtonEventArgs mouseEvent = new MouseButtonEventArgs(md, 0, MouseButton.Left);
    return mouseEvent;
}
```

Add a click event to one of your WPF controls:

```
private void btnDoSomeThing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Finally, Call the click event from any function:

```
btnDoSomeThing_Click(new object(), MouseClickEvent());
```

To simulate double clicking, add a double click event like PreviewMouseDoubleClick and make sure any code starts in a separate function:

```
private void lvFiles_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DoMouseDoubleClick(e);
}

private void DoMouseDoubleClick(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Add your logic here
}
```

To invoke the double click event, just call it from another function (like KeyDown):

```
private void someControl_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        DoMouseDoubleClick(e);
}
```