# Why isn't the mouse clicking when I am telling it to?

Tags: c#, winapi, cursor, mouse, emulation

I am using the following code from [How to simulate Mouse Click in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c) and I have found that it does not work. Here is the code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

    public void DoMouseClick()
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 882, 554, 0, 0);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoMouseClick();
    }
```

I have also tried replacing `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENT_LEFTUP...` with `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN & MOUSEEVENT_LEFTUP...` but still no luck. Other people have had success with this... Why am I not?

Comment: What version / bit depth of the OS are you running?

Comment: MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN and MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP in one call??

Comment: @AlexFarber Yes, other wise the mouse will just go down and not up, thus forth doing nothing

Comment: I mean: try mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN ...); mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP ...);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use mouse_event(), it has been superseded by SendInput().

There's a good reason for that, the return type for mouse_event() is *void*.  There isn't any way that Windows can tell you that you are doing it wrong.  SendInput returns UINT and reports an error by returning 0 and exposing the error code through GetLastError.

And you are definitely doing it wrong.  Sending a mouse event that has the button simultaneously up and down doesn't make sense.  You need to call it twice; down first, up next.