# C# Multiple mouse macros within form windows

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I want to make a windows form application that I can open multiple times.

When I click the "GO" button on the first form, I want the mouse to perform a series of clicks within the form (given by specific coordinates), while I still have control over the cursor using my hand-held mouse, so essentially there are 2 mice.

If I click the "GO" button on all forms, I want all the mice to perform a series of clicks within the corresponding form (all running in unison, not effecting one another), while I still have control over the hand-held mouse to do what I want I.E. browse the web.

Is this possible to do? IF so where would I start?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PInvoke` and call the `SendInput` API.
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge it is impossible to have two mice on one windows system, if you simulate a click somewhere it normally moves the mouse to that location.

You can try the lib Wolfgang suggested or you can use the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c)

As for it running multiple times you could just load up multiple threads all running the same code, like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[5]; // replace 5 with how many times you want to run it.
        for(int i = 0; i < threads.Length;i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyCode));
            threads[i].Start();
        }
    }

    static void MyCode()
    {
        //put code here
    }
```