# Need to reach the end of a flash movie embedded into HTML with C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, flash, selenium

I am attempting to use Selenium WebDriver in C# to make a single click on a page to skip to the end of a movie.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
data="flash.swf" width="100%" 
height="100%" bgcolor="#000000" id="player" name="[player" 
tabindex="0"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" 
value="always"><param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true"><param name="wmode" 
value="opaque"></object>
```

I am somewhat lost.  I tried searching for a simple click coordinate method for Selenium WebDriver, but with no luck.  I tried to look into using JavaScript to control the flash, but unsure what script I might use.
I am coding in C#, I am open to any potential solutions. My end goal is to simply skip to the end of the movie.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium can only control the browser DOM. To control other objects, see Genie, AutoIt, Sikuli, Robot, or any number of other tools / frameworks.

Comment: Any installed packages would only be local to my visual studios. I need it to be a code solution or file that I can "check in".

Comment: The libraries work and if I only needed them local to my box, that would be great. I'm going to consider this question answered and mark it so tomorrow with the link commented above. I thank you for showing me these libraries though. These are really cool. :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find this. I hope it helps for anyone who comes across this.

```
IMouse mouse = ((IHasInputDevices)driver).Mouse;
ILocatable locatableItem =   
    (ILocatable)Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("YOUR CSS"));
mouse.MouseMove(locatableItem.Coordinates, X, Y);
```

The needed libraries are:
using OpenQA.Selenium;