# Simulating a Mouse Double-Click is not working

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on my project in Windows Form and need to simulate a Mouse Click. I get coordinates from textbox and after pressing button it must make Double Click but unfortunately I it isn't making Click. Can anyone say the reason ? Here is a code :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

        private const int MOUSEEVENT_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENT_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENT_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);

        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c

Comment: Use `NumericUpDown` to input numbers.

Comment: btw, [``mouse_event``](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx) isn't supported anymore, use [``SendInput``](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [This MSDN discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c1112e9e-1a96-477f-8c71-e0e24e4f892f/simulate-doubleclick?forum=csharplanguage) you might have to wait between the clicks.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

private const int MOUSEEVENT_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENT_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENT_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//for C++ Builder

```
void SimulateMouseClick(TControl *pControl, Classes__1 MiceKey)
{
        TPoint p;
        int mX;
        int mY;
        INPUT mouse[3] = {0};
        TPublicControl *pCtl;
    
        DWORD dwDown, dwUp;
        UINT uiSleepTime;
    
switch (MiceKey)
{
  case ssLeft:
   dwDown = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
   dwUp   = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
   uiSleepTime = 0;
  break;

  case ssRight:
   dwDown = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
   dwUp   = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
   uiSleepTime = 0;
  break;

  case ssMiddle:
   dwDown = MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN;
   dwUp   = MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP;
   uiSleepTime = 0;
  break;

  case ssDouble:
   dwDown = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
   dwUp   = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
   uiSleepTime = GetDoubleClickTime()/10;
  break;
    
  default:
   return;
}
    
    
pCtl = (TPublicControl *)pControl;  //hack for properties public access, i.e. struct TPublicControl : public TControl {  __property OnClick; ... etc};
    
p = CenterPoint(pCtl->ClientRect);
p = pCtl->ClientToScreen(p);
    
mX = MulDiv(p.x, 65535, Screen->Width);
mY = MulDiv(p.y, 65535, Screen->Height);
    
 mouse[0].mi.dx          = mX;
 mouse[0].mi.dy          = mY;
 mouse[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE|MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE|MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK;
    
 mouse[1].mi.dwFlags     = dwDown;
 mouse[2].mi.dwFlags     = dwUp;
  
 SendInput(3, mouse, sizeof(INPUT));
 if(uiSleepTime)
  {
   Sleep(uiSleepTime); //system delay for catch doubleclick event
   SendInput(2, &mouse[1], sizeof(INPUT));
  }
}
```

Comment: This question is explicitly tagged for .NET/C#. Please answer the specific question. If you want to answer this question for C++, you can either find a question asking for this in C++—or even ask and answer yourself as a new question.