# Simulating Mouseclick - Mouse is not moving

Tags: c#, click, mouse

I tried [How to simulate Mouse Click in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c)

```
public void DoMouseClick(uint X, uint Y)
    {
        //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    }
```

My problem is, that the click got executed on that point, my cursor is and not on that point, I set for x and y. My coordinates aren´t wrong. I tried it also with x=1 and y=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;//0x02;
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;//0x04;

    public void Click(int x, int y)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        SetCursorPos(x, y);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```