# SendMessage can't send mouse coordination to game when simulation mouse click

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I'd like to simulate mouse click to a game and don't want my app take my mouse so I don't use mouve_event, I used SendMessage likes this:

```
int coordinates = clientPoint.Y << 16 | clientPoint.X;
SendMessage(wndHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, coordinates);
SendMessage(wndHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, coordinates);
```

I'd like to click on point X, Y but this code only clicks on last mouse position on my game.

How to make SendMessage click on point X, Y of my game?

Thank you all so much.

Comment: Did you tried moving the cursor position ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7121314/555111

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate Mouse Click in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c)

Comment: I don't want using mouse_event because it moves my cursor.

Comment: Why are you shifting your y axis?

Comment: lParam and wParam should be defined as int, because .NET long is 64-bit integer, and Win32 WPARAM and LPARAM are 32-bits type. To pack x and y to LPARAM I use LParam = (y << 16) | x;

Comment: Well, you are simulating a physical click on your mouse, so you physically have to move your cursor. What you could do is store the current position, move your cursor, click, and move your cursor to the previous stored position.