# Batch file to open program and click in specific area of the program

Tags: batch-file

I have one small program that creates windows and sql users called "`login.exe`"

I need a way to open the program, and click on the button "`Create`" and after `X seconds` close the program.

Is there any good way to do it? for example, execute the script every day at midnight, the program will `open`, `click "Create"` then `waits 10 sec`, and `close` the program.

It would be great if someone can help me with it because windows keep losing some users created after some time like every month I have to run that program.

Comment: There is no facility in pure batch files, i.e. command line interface, to interact with the GUI, you will need to leverage another language which provides this facility, Windows Script Host is one such option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Compo is right, batch files cannot interact with the GUI but...you could use another language like c++ or even python to directly interact with the GUI and give you the same output in the very same console format that a batch file would. I would recommend using c# or C++ to do this because you could still execute command line operations just as you would within a batch file.

Comment: Can you tell me the "name" of the search that I have to do in order to find results about interaction with programs or something like that? it would be great because I have no clue what to search for.

Comment: @AnoushkaIola,you didn't search for **batch file click button**? That is what I did and found the topic that I posted above.

Comment: @AnoushkaIola you could start here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-do-you-simulate-mouse-click-in-c

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)