# Simulating click and drag on Windows 10 Touch Keyboard

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-10

I'm trying to simulate click and drag on the [Windows 10 Touch keyboard](https://www.howtogeek.com/297443/how-to-use-handwriting-input-on-windows-10/), on its handwriting window using a C# app. I am using the following code -

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int x = 525;
        int y = 1500;
        SetCursorPos(x, y);

        MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftDown, x, y);
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2);
            SetCursorPos(++x, y);
        }
        MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftUp, x, y);

    }
}
```

The MouseOperations code is from the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-do-you-simulate-mouse-click-in-c). This works great for click and drag on MS Paint and I can see a line being drawn. But when I use the same code on the Windows 10 touch keyboard's handwriting view, it does not show a line being drawn, just one dot. I've tried different sleep times, but it does not work even though I can see the mouse cursor moving as expected - the line does not show. I tried simulating simple clicks on the keyboard view (not the handwriting view), and that also seems to work. How do I simulate mouse click and drag on the handwriting view of the keyboard? I hope to eventually use this code for Unity, so I'm not completely sure if I want to make a "UWP app" as some online [links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/input-injection) show - there seems to be a separate method for injecting events in UWP apps.

Comment: The keyboard might be using the newer pointer API/messages.

Comment: Simulating the click seems to work on the keyboard, so not sure what you mean here.

Comment: Maybe it uses WM_POINTER or raw input.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on this or point me to a link?

Comment: So, Your purpose is realizing this feature for Unity, right ?

Comment: Yes, for Unity.