# Double Click on another windows Application using C# application

Tags: c#, sendmessage, postmessage, sendinput

I need to left click, Right click and Double click on another windows based application via C# application using SendMessage or Post Message.
I am able to find window handle using FindWindow() method now i need to send/post message another application like left click(given x,y position), right click (given x,y position) and double click (passing given x,y position). 
Kindly do the help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet i stole from a [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416762/11754434). Wich was stolen from [here](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/321029-how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-in-c/).

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class Form1 : Form
    {
       [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
       public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
       //Mouse actions
       private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
       private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
       private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
       private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

       public Form1()
       {
       }

       public void DoMouseClick()
       {
          //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
          uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
          uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
          mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
       }

       //...other code needed for the application
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for response but here window handle not used then how it will be automatically click to another application? Thanks