# How to enable Media AutoPlay in Microsoft WebView2?

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core, webview2

I am using a WinForms application and within that I created a WebView2 instance to play media content using HTML5. I have been looking into documentation to find some way by which I can Enable AutoPlay in WebView2 such that my desktop application will play videos without user's interaction.

**Things that I have tried.**

- I changed the Registry following this [Documentation](https://admx.help/?Category=EdgeChromium&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Edge::AutoplayAllowed) without success
- I also enabled the AutoPlay from within Microsoft Edge but it did not have any effect.

Thank you!

Comment: WebView2 is not Edge, it's based on Chromium. The autoplay Policy here is a bit stricter. You can play video in a `<video>` or `<iframe>` elements, setting `<video src="someVideo.mp4" controls autoplay>` or, e.g., `<iframe src="someVideo.mp4" allow="autoplay; fullscreen">`, but to start it automatically you need to mute it.

Comment: I mean, e.g., `<video src="some source" controls autoplay muted>`

Comment: It does auto-play with audio if you set the `Source` property to `new Uri([video file path])`.

Comment: @Jimi Do you mean because of those square brackets which make it run? I don't think so.

Comment: What square brackets? Do you mean this: `[video file path]`? That's the standard way to imply *"a value to be provided"*. Which of course translates to e.g, `webView2.Source = new Uri(@"C:\Temp\somefile.mp4");`

Comment: New chromium browsers simply do not allow autoplay even if you pass autoplay flag. They allow autoplay with muted but I do not want that. I wanted a video to be auto played without audio muted.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested to pass the Video `file:///`  path directly to the `Source` property. In this case, the Video is auto-played with audio. The `muted` limitation is related to the HTML. About the *limitation* of Chromium browsers, I described this in my first comment.

Comment: I see, thanks for the input. Unfortunately the file is coming from an API so the path will contain http.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it's the same thing. You can pass the HTTP/HTTPS address to the Source property and it will auto-play with audio. Didn't you try it?

Comment: I haven't actually. Sorry I didn't get a chance to do it. But I will. However, I believe this seems to be fixed in future as bypassing the browser's policy will not be possible always.

Comment: @Jimi your tip did not work for me when I tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a thorough research, I found a solution as well as my team lead also found a solution.

The first solution that I sorted, is a workaround to perform a click on WebView2 window right after you initialize the WebView2, using this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7121314/11325901). This can be achieved by registering to `WebView2.NavigationCompleted` event.

The second solution is more elegant and appropriate; although it needs final touches, anyone can improve it according to their own preferences.

```
var options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions("--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required");
var path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\92.0.902.67";
var environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(path, null, options);

var webView = new WebView2();
await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(environment);
```

Note that the variable **"path"** contains the directory where your WebView2 runtime executive file is located. The path will be changed when a new version is released by Microsoft. You can also download a WebView2 fixed runtime and include those within your project dependencies.

Comment: I get a compiler error at:

`var environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(path, null, options);`

Error message:
"The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<WebView2>'."

But why? The method *IS* awaitable.

Comment: In addition to have a Method with Task<T> return type, you also have to put 'async' keyword there. Like: public async Task<T> MyMethod() { ... your method body ... }

Comment: It also works if you pass null as the first (path) argument to CreateAsync, which has the advantage that it's not tied to a particular version or install location of Edge.

Answer (score 3):

It can be so. It helped me

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS", "--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required");
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: wow so simple solution for a nasty problem